# Is there a way to copy data from your iphone internal storage to your mac?

Tags: iphone, data-transfer

On a windows pc - a folder called `iPhone -> Internal Storage` is available to copy things from your iphone to your pc.

I would like to do the same with my macbook.

Where is the iphone internal storage mounted so I can `cp` it to my mac?

Comment: It isn't. What kind of data do you want to copy, there might be other ways.

Comment: Pictures and videos

Comment: Running Image Capture with the iPhone connected should work.

Comment: Windows only does this because it doesn't integrate properly to the iPhone structure. On Mac, the internal storage is never directly exposed in the same way.

Comment: If "internal storage” refers to Apple’s Files - you could create a shared folder on your Mac, connect from the iPhone, and copy from and to it.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Odd, is it not?... Windows doesn't integrate properly, but it allows the OP to do what he wants to do in the way he wants to do it. Or - do you mean the files get mangled in copying?

Comment: @Seamus - Windows has to mount the phone as a PTP device, so you can see the  DCIM folder , allowing the user to dig through the unfathomable hierarchy without a safety net ;) I don't see it as a 'good' thing, really.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Perhaps not, but do you consider not being able to copy a spreadsheet file from your phone to your Mac a good thing? Is this a case of "difficult/dangerous" for Windows vs "impossible" for macOS?

Comment: It mounts the DCIM folder, it doesn't open up file access to the entire phone. If you want to manually copy something like a spreadsheet you'll need to use iTunes, which can access the file structure unencrypted.

Answer (score 1):

1. If it is just photos and videos from the Photos app, [Airdrop](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204144) would be a quick way to move some photos and videos from your iPhone to your Mac. Make sure Airdrop is [enabled](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203106) on your mac.
2. You could try an app called [iFunbox](https://www.i-funbox.com/) to access some files on your iPhone. It is limited due to Apple's OS, but maybe it works for what you want to achieve.
3. If you use iCloud, you can enable the [sync](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204264) function. All photos and videos from your phone's photo app will be accessible in your Mac's Photos app. You can export them from there.

Comment: iFunbox is not a Mac app. Please consider all of the question when writing an answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @AndyGriffiths [iFunBox](https://www.i-funbox.com/en/index.html) appears to have a macOS version. Have you tried it?

Comment: Actually no. I didn't know a Mac version existed. All the links I found while verifying the suggestion pointed to Win7 versions or dodgy websites with expired SSL certs. Thx for the pointer. Doesn't look like something I'd want to try anyway, been burnt by third party iOS file managers before, and that was 10 years ago...